# trigger parameterized build with groovy variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an Jenkins Freestyle job with an system groovy script in the Build area. After executing the script I want to trigger a pipeline job. The pipeline job needs a variable who gets defined inside my groovy scipt.

```
if(condition1){
    var = 'String1'
}else{
    var = 'String2'
}
```

But I need to get acces to my variable `var` at the "post-build-action" step at the "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" option to trigger my pipeline with `var` as parameter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem the following way:

Before building I define a parameter to use the parameterized trigger plugin. Inside my system groovy script I override it with

```
def newMailParameter = new StringParameterValue('MAIL_PARAM', mailsFromWS)
build.replaceAction(new ParametersAction(newMailParameter))
```

Now I can trigger the next job and use my parameter `MAIL_PARAM` inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can simply write your variables as key-value pairs in a property file and load it in your post-build-action by specifying `Parameters from properties file`.

You can save your property file like this

```
def fw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("params.properties",true), 'UTF-8')
def props = new Properties()
props.setProperty('TESTPARAM', var)
props.store(fileWriter, null)
fw.close()
```

Comment: Ahh ok. I tried it but I have some trouble so save the properties file. I use `Properties props = new Properties()` and `props.setProperty('TESTPARAM', var)` to save the variable. With `println props.getProperty('TESTPARAM')` I am able to read it but I have no file to give to my trigger plugin

Comment: Well, you have to **save** your file in your Workspace using `props.store(...)`

Comment: Edited my answer with an example (not tested)

Comment: mhm I always get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Jenkins_Slave\workspace\tmp\tmp2\tmp3\test.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)`. But the path is defenitely right

Comment: and with `C:/Jenkins_Slave/workspace/tmp/tmp2/tmp3/test.properties` ? Or just use relative paths (answer once again edited)

Comment: Sorry I copied the console output. Inside the script I use`/` but Jenkins formats them to `\\`

Comment: found out that the buildstep (system groovy script) writes the properties file to the masters filesystem...